# How to add a folder to the favorites bar in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome

i'm using `gnome-shell 3.0.0.1`, is there a way i can add a folder shortcut or custom launcher (the same way in regular gnome panels) to the gnome-shell favorites dock bar?

[image: Gnome-shell favorites dock bar]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add a Downloads folder to the favorites bar in Gnome Shell:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/downloads.desktop
nano downloads.desktop
```

I set the first 4 lines to:

```
Name=Downloads
Comment=Access and organize your downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
Icon=folder-download
```

Now do one of the following:

- Log out and back in. Or,
- Run this in a Terminal window:

  ```
  nautilus -q
  ```

  Then open the Application Launcher with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run:

  ```
  nautilus
  ```

Search for *Downloads* in the Dash and then drag the **Applications** shortcut (as you saw, the **Places** shortcut won't work) to the favourites bar.

You can browse for other icon names by looking in `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/24/` for instance.

By default, Nautilus will attempt to open pathnames in your home directory. If you want to access a folder not in your home directory, just put the full path (like `/etc/apt` )

By the way, the favorites are stored in org.gnome.shell favorite-apps. I prefer to use **dconf-editor** to browse around and tweak stuff, but you can  also use gsettings directly from the command line.

Thanks @fossfreedom for the assist!

Comment: Jeremy - if you copy from /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications and rename the file,  you can add the new desktop shortcut to dconf-editor favourite-apps string.  Thus you dont need an admin account.

Comment: This work great for me (Pop!_os 19.10) to add a recents folder using "con= folder-recent" and "exec=nemo recents:\\\". Basically, any of those *.desktop files in /usr/share/applications will come up in the applications shortcut and can be made a favourite.