# How do I search for folders in the dash?

Tags: gnome

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10. I installed also gnome-shell and everything works great. I just have a small problem.

In Ubuntu 12.04 when I typed the name of a folder in the dash of gnome 3 I would get an icon where I could open this folder.

Now in Ubuntu 12.10 I just get results for programs and configuration but no folders.
Does anyone has the same problem? is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add manually any folder you want to the dash (and to the sidebar). Just follow the instructions here:

[How to add a folder to the favorites bar in Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40382/how-to-add-a-folder-to-the-favorites-bar-in-gnome-shell?rq=1)

In the *.desktop files you can also add custom locations and paths like:

```
Exec=nautilus /mnt/home/yourname/Dropbox/
```

or for the icon:

```
Icon=/path/to/icon/random.png
```

It worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit with Gnome 3.6.0. Of course, it could be a little easier.... like d&d...

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the searching you describe was among recent folders, not all folders, and it should not have changed

Comment: I used to get 3 types of search results: programs, configurations and folders. These 3 were separated sections. Now I just get programs and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10, and it's a bit of a shame that the tools necessary to do this are still not built into gnome shell settings.

The current solution is:
sudo apt-get install tracker

Then for a gui for this command line tool, run:
sudo apt-get install tracker-gui

You can then run tracker-gui by typing "tracker" into the gnome search bar, and clicking on the "search and indexing" icon that appears (icon with a paw-print)

Under the indexing tab, I set the Limitations radio button to "While other applications are running" to support fastest possible indexing, and then went the the locations tab, and added my dropbox path, click Apply, then close the dialog. After a restart of the computer and some waiting think it was a few hours in my case, but I have a LOT of files (indexing happens silently), I now have the contents of my dropbox folder searched automatically by the search utility.

Hope it helps!

-C